# MWPhotoBrowser does not show display image name for single image in navigation title

Tags: ios, iphone

I am using MWPhotoBrowser to display images in navigation. For multiple images it is working fine. But when displaying one image(number of images is 1) it does not display image name as title of navigation bar. How do i fix that? here is the code of delegate method:

```
- (void) photoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser didDisplayPhotoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
NSLog(@"Photo displayed");
if (index < [self.imagesGallery count]) {
    NSString *imageName = [self.imagesGallery objectAtIndex:index];

    photoBrowser._titleText = [imageName stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    NSLog(@"Title: %@", photoBrowser._titleText);
    NSString *element = [[[imageName stringByDeletingPathExtension] componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"] objectAtIndex:1];
    int index_ = [deficiencesShort indexOfObject:element];
    photoBrowser._actionButton.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Go To %@ Deficiency", [deficiences objectAtIndex:index_]];
}
```

}

For single image, NSLog(@"Title: %@", photoBrowser._titleText) displays image name as output but does not set as navigation bar title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you make some changes with MWPhotoBrowser library, show me your code.

Setting title of of MWPhotoBrowser's Navigation:

1. add name property in MWPhoto
2. modifier updateNavigation method, in handleMWPhotoLoadingDidEndNotification, pass a title in updateNAvigation (two functions in MWPhotoBrowser.m)

Answer (score 0):

Put below condition in `updateNavigation` method in `MWPhotoBrowser.m` file

remove `self.title = nil;`and add this condition in else part.

```
    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(photoBrowser:titleForPhotoAtIndex:)]) {
        self.title = [_delegate photoBrowser:self titleForPhotoAtIndex:_currentPageIndex];
    }
    else {
        self.title = nil;
    }
```

> Make sure you need to implement `photoBrowser:titleForPhotoAtIndex` delegate.